# Filtering query in C# based on dictionary within each entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a query coming from the database and I want to filter the query based on a column in the table "ExtraProperties" which is written in a json format in Sql but when getting the query it is mapped to a Dictionary<string,object?>, this is the query and this is what i tried to do :

```
        var query = await repository.GetQueryableAsync();
        query = query.Where(i => (bool)EF.Property<Dictionary<string, object?>>(i, "ExtraProperties")["AutoGenerated"] == true);
```

"ExtraPorperties" is the property , "AutoGenerated" is the key on the dictionary and I know that the value is of type "bool".
however this code gives me an error says "The Linq query could not be translated" so my question is , is there any other way to filter the records based on the key-value dictionary "ExtraProperties"?

please note that the method is generic and C# does not recognize any property within entities inside the query.

Comment: Would it be easiest to get the dictionary or deserialize it into a dictionary first and then use a more simple linq statement? Something like, 
`var x = dict.Where(i => i.Key == "AutoGenerated" && (bool)i.Value == (bool)true);`

Comment: It cannot be done, because the method is very generic and C# does not recognize any property in the entity

Comment: Okay, maybe the issue is that it is just querying the database then it is looking for actual sql type, which is a string in c# and it cannot recognize the dictionary.

Comment: this is exactly the problem, is there any way to get "ExtraProperties" column as Json in my query ? and then try to filter it ??

Comment: Well the json is just a string. So I am not familiar with the `GetQueryableAsync` but just treat it as a string instead of a dictionary and then try to deserialize it. Try to treat "ExtraProperties" as a string first and then try to deserialize it into a dictionary. To deserialize use newtonsoft or something similar and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(extraPropertiesString);`